# mini session factory and realsession factory

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I wanna create mini session and fullsession factory using threads. the full session factory is on second thread. the concept is do initial login details with minisession and wait for fullsession for other things. i implemented thread but there is some problem when the code hits buildsessionfactory(second one). when not on threads the code works fine. how do i implement minisession just for activities like login details. I think one of the problem is also how to start thread(GetFullSessionFactoryFor).

```
  public sealed class NHibernateSessionManager
    {
    static bool sessionFactoryReady = false;
    #region Thread-safe, lazy Singleton
    private string _sessionFactoryConfigPath = null;

    public static NHibernateSessionManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.NHibernateSessionManager;
        }
    }


    private NHibernateSessionManager() { }


    private class Nested
    {
        static Nested() { }
        internal static readonly NHibernateSessionManager NHibernateSessionManager =
            new NHibernateSessionManager();
    }

    #endregion


    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactoryFor(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        GetFullSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath);
        while (!sessionFactoryReady) Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return (ISessionFactory)sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
    }

    private void GetFullSessionFactoryFor(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
         {
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionFactoryConfigPath),
                      "sessionFactoryConfigPath may not be null nor empty");



        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = (ISessionFactory)sessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];


        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            Check.Require(File.Exists(sessionFactoryConfigPath),
                          "The config file at '" + sessionFactoryConfigPath + "' could not be found");

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.SetInterceptor(new NHInterceptor());
            cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);



            FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
                .Mappings(m =>
                {
                    m.FluentMappings
                         .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("someassembly"))
                         .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
                                          OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                                          DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                                          DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                                          DefaultCascade.None()
                                         )
                         .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<"someDateconventionobject">()
                         ;
                });


            ;
            sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
            }

            sessionFactories.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory);


            cfg.SetInterceptor(new NHInterceptor());
            cfg.Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath);

            fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(cfg);

            string userDataPath = cfg.GetProperty("connection.connection_string").ToUpper();
            userDataPath = userDataPath.Replace("somevalue", "");
            userDataPath = userDataPath.Replace(";somevalue", "");


            string[] folderList = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(userDataPath);
            bool firstFolder = true;

            foreach (string folder in folderList)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(folder + "\\somedatabase"))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (firstFolder)
                        {

                            fluentConfiguration = fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("sessionfactoryname", folder.ToLower()))
                                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("connectionstring", ""))
                                .Mappings(m =>
                                {
                                    m.FluentMappings
                                        .AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("otherassembly"))
                                        .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always(),
                                                         OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                                                         DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                                                         DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                                                         DefaultCascade.None()
                                                        )
                                        .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<"somedateconventionobject">()
                                        ;
                                }
                                         )
                                ;


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fluentConfiguration = fluentConfiguration.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("sessionfactoryname", "name"))
                                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("connectionstring", "value"));
                        }

                        sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory(); ------here is the problem
                        sessionFactories.Add(folder.ToLower(), sessionFactory);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new EncoreException(e);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        sessionFactoryReady = true;

        });

    }


    public void RegisterInterceptorOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, IInterceptor interceptor, int sessionId)
    {
        ISession session = (ISession)ContextSessions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {
            throw new CacheException("You cannot register an interceptor once a session has already been opened");
        }

        GetSessionFrom(sessionFactoryConfigPath, interceptor, sessionId);
    }

    public ISession GetSessionFrom(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        return GetSessionFrom(sessionFactoryConfigPath, null, sessionId);
    }


    private ISession GetSessionFrom(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, IInterceptor interceptor, int sessionId)
    {
        ISession session = (ISession)ContextSessions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        if (session == null)
        {
            if (interceptor != null)
            {
                session = GetSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath).OpenSession(interceptor);
            }
            else
            {
                session = GetSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath).OpenSession();
            }
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
            ContextSessions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()] = session;
        }

        Check.Ensure(session != null, "session was null");

        return session;
    }


    public System.Data.IDbConnection GetDbConnection(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ISession session = GetSessionFrom(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionId);
        return session.Connection;
    }


    public void CloseSessionOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ISession session = (ISession)ContextSessions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {

            session.Close();


            sessionList[sessionId] = false;
            reuseSessionList.Push(sessionId);
        }

        ContextSessions.Remove(sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString());
    }

    public ITransaction BeginTransactionOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = (ITransaction)ContextTransactions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            transaction = GetSessionFrom(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionId).BeginTransaction();
            ContextTransactions.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString(), transaction);
        }

        return transaction;
    }

    public void CommitTransactionOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = (ITransaction)ContextTransactions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        try
        {
            if (HasOpenTransactionOn(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionId))
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                ContextTransactions.Remove(sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (HibernateException)
        {
            RollbackTransactionOn(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionId);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public bool HasOpenTransactionOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = (ITransaction)ContextTransactions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        return transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && !transaction.WasRolledBack;
    }

    public void RollbackTransactionOn(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, int sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = (ITransaction)ContextTransactions[sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString()];

        try
        {
            if (HasOpenTransactionOn(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionId))
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }

            ContextTransactions.Remove(sessionFactoryConfigPath + "//" + sessionId.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
    public int GetSession()
    {
        int getSessionId = 0;
        if (reuseSessionList.Count > 0)
        {
            getSessionId = reuseSessionList.Pop();
            sessionList[getSessionId] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            getSessionId = nextSessionId;
            sessionList.Add(true);
            nextSessionId++;
        }
        return getSessionId;

    }




    private Hashtable ContextTransactions
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInWebContext())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY] == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY] = new Hashtable();

                return (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY];
            }
            else
            {
                if (CallContext.GetData(TRANSACTION_KEY) == null)
                    CallContext.SetData(TRANSACTION_KEY, new Hashtable());

                return (Hashtable)CallContext.GetData(TRANSACTION_KEY);
            }
        }
    }


    private Hashtable ContextSessions
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInWebContext())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] = new Hashtable();

                return (Hashtable)HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY];
            }
            else
            {
                if (CallContext.GetData(SESSION_KEY) == null)
                    CallContext.SetData(SESSION_KEY, new Hashtable());

                return (Hashtable)CallContext.GetData(SESSION_KEY);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsInWebContext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current != null;
    }

    private Hashtable sessionFactories = new Hashtable();
    private const string TRANSACTION_KEY = "CONTEXT_TRANSACTIONS";
    private const string SESSION_KEY = "CONTEXT_SESSIONS";

    private List<bool> sessionList = new List<bool>();
    private Stack<int> reuseSessionList = new Stack<int>();
    private int nextSessionId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- firstFolder is never set to false, therefor mappings are added for each subfolder and that lengthens the creation of the sessionfactory.
- GetDbConnection should be left out. it is simple `GetSessionFrom().Connection` or even better `GetSessionFrom().CreateSqlQuery()` so no value gained here
- Threads don't add any value at all because all is created lazyly.
- sessions already have a unique id, no need to manage your own.

i dont understand your logic with the subdirectories so i left them out. if you explain the idea i could see if i can come up with better code to handle them

revised version of your code

```
public sealed class NHibernateSessionManager
{
    // Constants
    private const string FACTORY_KEY = "CONTEXT_FACTORIES";
    private const string SESSION_KEY = "CONTEXT_SESSIONS";
    private const string TRANSACTION_KEY = "CONTEXT_TRANSACTIONS";

    private IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory> SessionFactories = new Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory>();

    // not really nessesary because creating NHibernateSessionManager is very cheap
    #region Thread-safe, lazy Singleton
    private NHibernateSessionManager() { }

    public static NHibernateSessionManager Instance
    {
        get { return Nested.NHibernateSessionManager; }
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        static Nested() { }
        internal static readonly NHibernateSessionManager NHibernateSessionManager =
            new NHibernateSessionManager();
    }

    #endregion

    private ISessionFactory GetSessionFactoryFor(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        Check.Require(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionFactoryConfigPath), "sessionFactoryConfigPath may not be null nor empty");

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];

        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            // logic to configure and build the factory

            Check.Require(File.Exists(sessionFactoryConfigPath),
                "The config file at '" + sessionFactoryConfigPath + "' could not be found");

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                .Configure(sessionFactoryConfigPath)
                .SetInterceptor(new NHInterceptor());

            string assemblypath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sessionFactoryConfigPath), "whatever");
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblypath);
            sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(cfg)
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                            .AddFromAssembly(assembly)
                            .Conventions.Add(
                                DefaultLazy.Always(),
                                OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.All()),
                                DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue(),
                                DynamicInsert.AlwaysFalse(),
                                DefaultCascade.None())
                            .Conventions.AddAssembly(assembly))
                .BuildSessionFactory();

            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("cfg.BuildSessionFactory() returned null.");
            }
            SessionFactories.Add(sessionFactoryConfigPath, sessionFactory);

            // !!!DirectoryLogic ommitted because doesn't understand at all!!!
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private IDictionary<Guid, ISession> Sessions
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInWebContext())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] = new Dictionary<Guid, ISession>();

                return (IDictionary<Guid, ISession>)HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY];
            }
            else
            {
                if (CallContext.GetData(SESSION_KEY) == null)
                    CallContext.SetData(SESSION_KEY, new Dictionary<string, ISession>());

                return (IDictionary<Guid, ISession>)CallContext.GetData(SESSION_KEY);
            }
        }
    }

    private IDictionary<Guid, ITransaction> Transactions
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInWebContext())
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY] == null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY] = new Dictionary<Guid, ITransaction>();

                return (IDictionary<Guid, ITransaction>)HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY];
            }
            else
            {
                if (CallContext.GetData(TRANSACTION_KEY) == null)
                    CallContext.SetData(TRANSACTION_KEY, new Dictionary<string, ITransaction>());

                return (IDictionary<Guid, ITransaction>)CallContext.GetData(TRANSACTION_KEY);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsInWebContext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current != null;
    }

    #region public

    public Guid CreateSessionFor(string sessionFactoryConfigPath)
    {
        return CreateSessionFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath, null);
    }

    public Guid CreateSessionFor(string sessionFactoryConfigPath, IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        var factory = SessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath];
        if (factory == null)
        {
            factory = GetSessionFactoryFor(sessionFactoryConfigPath);
            SessionFactories[sessionFactoryConfigPath] = factory;
        }
        ISession session;
        if (interceptor != null)
            session = factory.OpenSession(interceptor);
        else
            session = factory.OpenSession();

        Guid sessionId = session.GetSessionImplementation().SessionId;
        Sessions.Add(sessionId, session);

        return sessionId;
    }

    public ISession GetSession(Guid sessionId)
    {
        var session = Sessions[sessionId];
        Check.Ensure(session != null, "there is no session with id '" + sessionId + "'");

        return session;
    }

    public void CloseSession(Guid sessionId)
    {
        ISession session = Sessions[sessionId];

        if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
        {
            session.Close();
        }

        Sessions.Remove(sessionId);
    }

    public ITransaction BeginTransactionOn(Guid sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = Transactions[sessionId];

        if (transaction == null)
        {
            transaction = GetSession(sessionId).BeginTransaction();
            Transactions.Add(sessionId, transaction);
        }

        return transaction;
    }

    public void CommitTransactionOn(Guid sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = Transactions[sessionId];

        try
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (HibernateException)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Transactions.Remove(sessionId);
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransactionOn(Guid sessionId)
    {
        ITransaction transaction = Transactions[sessionId];

        try
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Transactions.Remove(sessionId);

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: why? you start the thread when you need the result and wait for its completion, basicly the same as dont useing threads altogether. To speed things up (which is seldom needed) you would have to start the thread long befor you actually use the result, but since you dont know which factories are used at runtime, how could you possibly create them at startuptime?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions and helps. I am doing a wpf application using fleunt nhibernate. actually the requirement is creation of mini and fullsession. mini session factory is just for login details until full session is ready. how would you implement it if it has to be done using threads. suppose minisession factory is required for user class. and remaining entities wait for fullsession. where n how would you start the threads .kindly please give an example of how and where would you start the thread